# AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties when testing on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

It's getting really frustrating to test any apps at all. 
I start up the emulator and run the app the first time and it works and immediately starts throwing this in the ADB Logs

```
DeviceMonitor: Failed to connect to client '2560': EOF
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5554: device offline
```

Logcat displays nothing. I've tried everything to stop this. Killing and starting the adb server does not solve the problem. I have to restart the AVD.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem … I'm on OS X 10.10

Comment: I'm now using http://www.genymotion.com which works without giving cryptic error messages

Answer (score 9):

This usually happens because android emulator is just to slow and adb command times out. But you have parameter that you can set to increase this timeouts.

If you are running adb commands through gradle. For example `connnectedCheck`. You can use android plugin DSL to set this parameter as shown blow

```
android {
    adbOptions {
        timeOutInMs 60000 // set timeout to 1 minute
    }
}
```

This was added in android gradle plugin 1.2.0. Unfortunately it only works if you have multidex enabled. For some reason they forgot to include it for single apk builds. But there is a workaround to handle this. You can just call static method as show below.

```
com.android.ddmlib.DdmPreferences.setTimeOut(60000)
```

If you are running adb commands directly with adb you have an option to set environment variable that will handle this.

```
export ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=5
```

Keep in mind that `ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT` is set in seconds and not in milliseconds as in gradle DSL.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to help either. I think my problem is, that the emulator is not starting up at all (the screen stays black and no Android logo is shown). But I'll probably award the bounty to you, because of your detailed answer.

Comment: perfect answer, I was having an issue with travis taking a lot of time to connect and sometimes I got FAILED builds just because of the timeout, now everything is passing correctly!

Answer (score 6):

Try with this i hope it will help you.

1-adb kill-server
2-adb start-server to restart the adb.
It can be found in your android sdk directory, subfolder plattform-tools.
or
Try to locking and unlocking your emulator by clicking F7 and Check the logcat  when you do this.

Comment: Using `kill-server` and `start-server` makes no difference. The logcat is empty, because the emulator doesn't even properly connect with Android Studio. In my case I can't even see the Android logo when the simulator is starting up, but the screen stays black.

Comment: Are you using an ARM or Intel Image?

Comment: Thanks, killing the adb server worked for me. I was trying to install an app on my connected device and for some reason I kept getting `TimeoutException getting properties for device`. Running `adb devices` was also extremely slow. After killing the adb server `adb devices` was snappy again, and installation of the app worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me with a real device.

Try revoking USB debugging authorizations (from device Settings->Developer options).
Then reconnect the device and give the authorization.

Answer (score 0):

My advice to anyone using the Emulator is to get off AVD. Get a real device or download Genymotion. The free version gets the Job done.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue, and I run

adb devices

in Terminal and my device is showing offline I restarted the device it started working for me. But you you are frequently getting this issue the restart is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

The USB cable connecting the phone to your PC affects the adb devices offline/device status. Try replacing the cable with a known working one.