# com.android.ddmlib.InstallException on CircleCi when trying to run tests

Tags: android, continuous-integration, circleci

I did some searching around for this exception and saw that it's logged with Google as an Android bug, the only thing is it has been marked as fixed and released by them in an Android Studio release. However I am still experiencing it.

This is the full exception from CircleCi:

```
com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:117)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:130)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:894)
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:113)
    ... 8 more
```

It happens when it gets to the `./gradlew --stacktrace connectedAndroidTest` command in my circle.yml file.

Some other StackOverflow questions suggested setting a timeout, they were using TravisCI not CircleCi, but I tried it anyway and it has not worked. I set the timeout to 20minutes, but it still crashes. This is getting very annoying because all my builds are failing when they are passing on my machine.

Does anyone know the fix to this? Fine Google had a bug, and they supposedly fixed it, but CircleCi seem to still be having this problem, so the problem must still be there.

Would really appreciate some advice on this, CircleCi support is in another timezone so when I go to bed they are sending messages to me but I can't reply to the next morning when they are sleeping, so this has gone on for a week now and I've got no help from them.

Anyway, thanks for any help in advance. I can post my circle.yml file if you need it to help debug.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30254848/1262159) is what we generally suggest, and for now we haven’t found a better way to handle this kind of exception, unfortunately.

Comment: is there a way to run my tests without having to boot up an emulator, because I feel this is what is causing the downfall, since the bug relates to connecting the build with the emulator. Can I change something in my circle.yml file to do this?

Comment: @RED_ My understanding is that you need to start the simulator to be able to run the tests. I might be wrong, though. Did you try out the suggestions mentioned in that  comment?

Comment: I did try the suggestions above, I tried them quite a while back with no success. For the time being I have disabled CircleCi and will look into other options like Travis or try to contact CircleCi support again. This has become very painful to setup, and costing a lot of time.

Comment: @RED_ I feel your pain :( Would be great to get to the root of that issue.