# Android Emulator not showing app and emulator not found error

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

Well I would like to start my problem by stating that I have been trying to figure out what's wrong with my system(Windows 10) because `Android Studio` doesn't read the emulator properly or there is a file missing or some kind of error! 
Also I performed several reinstallation of Android Studio. I formatted my system and did every possible thing for the emulator to work but the simple Hello World program doesn't run too.
The error message is:

> Error: adb rejected command:
>   com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device 'emulator-5556'
>   not found.

Please help me guys, I am a beginner and I have stuck on my android classes because of this! 
Thank You :(

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817190/adbcommandrejectedexception-getting-properties-when-testing-on-emulator) which is similar to yours. Also, did you enable virtualization in BIOS? What is your CPU and RAM?

Comment: Unfortunately, Virtualization is not possible (as I checked after you stated) on Windows 10 Home Edition, the one which I have right now.
My System's CPU: Intel Core i5-4200 
RAM: 4 GB
System Type: x64-based
And one thing that I want to mention (rather, to rectify my question) that my emulator is working but the designed app never show up even when there's no error in the code. But the error shows that the device emulator not found!
And thanks a lot for replying, I am really looking forward to get my problem solved ASAP :)

Comment: I don't think that Operating System matters, I'm using windows 10 Education edition, and virtualization is working. Just restart your PC and go to BIOS, try and enable virtualization.